# Can I install a python package for all users (with setuptools in develop mode)

Tags: python, setuptools, multi-user

I found out that packages that I installed with setuptools are not accessible by other users. I understand that this behavior is logical, especially because I installed them in develop mode. However I would like to give other users on my server the access to these packages: they are quite complicated to install.

So my questions are:

1. for the future, is there a way to do (develop) install for all users, or some multiuser mode (eg. group)?
2. Is there a way to "simply" give access to such packages?

For both, I guess the main trouble are about dependencies.

[I am running ubuntu 13.04 (I can update if necessary), but answer for any OS are welcome]

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your installation command with `sudo` and you will install the package globally.

Comment: That's all? Isn't there possible risk of lost dependencies?

Comment: This is apparently not a good practice to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted/33004920#33004920

Comment: didn't seem to work in my case, it said the requirement was already met