# How to uninstall setuptools in mac

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I try to upgrade(or uninstall) setuptools:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

but I got an error like this

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/w8zdr8_d3090z1r38l11v0r00000gn/T/pip-0H2uCV-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

When I use command

```
sudo pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
```

according to

> [Upgrading setuptools on OSX El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234665/upgrading-setuptools-on-osx-el-capitan)

Though there is no error, the setuptools does not upgrade actually.

How can I upgrade or even uninstall the setuptools?

Comment: You should not be trying to manage the OS-installed Python libraries with `pip`.  Create a virtual environment or similar, where you can install whichever version you like of every library you need without mucking with the files the system is depending on.