# Something screwy with pip/python packages after hard-drive crash

Tags: python, osx-elcapitan

He everyone,

I recently had a harddrive corruption. Luckily I had all my files backed up by the online service CrashPlan.

This program only grabs files from the /users/username director, so when I restored my computer after reformatting my harddrive, I just made sure that the user file that was restored was the admin user on the computer and viola, everything was (almost) back to normal.

I was unable to start up my ipython, so I tried a pip-install. Turns out my pip was also gone (weird), so I redownloaded pip. Then when trying to install ipython I ran into a roadblock, [which was solved by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234665/upgrading-setuptools-on-osx-el-capitan)

However, when I try to start up ipython or ipython notebook from the command line, I get this error:

```
biot21-159-dhcp:Downloads kevin$ ipython
-bash: ipython: command not found
```

I tried booting up a new terminal session--no luck. Any ideas?

BTW, I'm running a late 2011 macbook pro with OSX 10.11 (ElCapitan)

---

EDIT:
so doing a reinstall of python using homebrew `brew install python` and then using `pip install ipython` did the job. Interestingly, I no longer have to add `--user python` after the pip statement. I don't know enough to answer why that is, but maybe someone out there that knows more could?

Comment: Re: why you don't need `--user python` after brew-installing python; The reason is that you don't need special permissions to use pip when you're not using the built-in Python that comes with El Capitan. You can read more on it here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/how-to-use-pip-after-the-el-capitan-max-os-x-upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think those binaries are stored in your `/users/<username>` directory, unfortunately. So you'll need to re-install those from scratch.

I would recommend you install those applications using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and that includes installing Python through `brew` as well, rather than tacking stuff onto the OS-bundled Python.

```
brew install python
```

Python will then install into e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python`

Then use pip which you'll get bundled with the brew-installed Python, and which you can use to `pip install ipython`. Just make sure you're executing `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip` in this case:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip install ipython
```

However, depending on your use case, you might want to consider installing ipython into a virtualenv.

Edit: As mentioned in my comment to your question, you can read more [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/how-to-use-pip-after-the-el-capitan-max-os-x-upgrade) about why you should probably leave the OS-bundled Python alone in OS X.

Comment: But I did reinstall ipython just now. IPython is still not booting up... Maybe I am misinterpreting your comment?