# Ansible roles/packages - Ansible Galaxy - error on installation MAC OSX

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-galaxy

Im trying to install ansible-galaxy roles on Mac OS X El Capitan via CLI

```
$ ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR! Unexpected Exception: (setuptools 1.1.6 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=11.3'))
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-galaxy", line 73, in <module>
    mycli = getattr(__import__("ansible.cli.%s" % sub, fromlist=[myclass]), myclass)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/galaxy.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ansible.galaxy.role import GalaxyRole
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/galaxy/role.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ansible.playbook.role.requirement import RoleRequirement
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ansible.playbook.play import Play
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ansible.playbook.base import Base
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/base.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ansible.parsing.vault import VaultLib
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import SHA256 as c_SHA256
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py", line 15, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces import HashBackend
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2797, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 580, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
VersionConflict: (setuptools 1.1.6 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=11.3'))
```

Comment: Could you add the file you are trying to install to your question, please?

Comment: Im trying to setup this https://github.com/roots/roots-example-project.com Install external Ansible roles/packages

# @ roots-example-project.com/trellis
$ ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml

Comment: Looks like it provides Vagrant. I would just use that to setup the instance

Comment: Yes, but before the Vagrant init, I need to install the Ansible roles/packages, and there's when i get the error

Comment: Ohh, right. Its hard to read your error, but it appears to be saying something about one of your python packages is outdated.

Comment: Try this link to update all pip packages.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip

Comment: I also tried to upgrade the python setuptools via pip (sudo -H pip install setuptools --upgrade) but I got an exception error

Comment: Fixed after an upgrade to the python setuptools http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234665/upgrading-setuptools-on-osx-el-capitan

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Run the following to upgrade setuptools under the `python` user:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools --user python
```

For some reason, the way things are installed inside OS X (and in my case, under CentOS 7 inside a Docker container), the setuptools package doesn't get installed correctly under the right user.

Comment: On my Mac, running that reinstalled setuptools-1.1.6.
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-22.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 1.6MB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: python in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-1.1.6

Comment: Even though I got the same message than @rhuffstedtler I didn't receive the warning anymore and I could proceed with the Ansible playbook I was running.

Comment: I added setuptools=11.3 to my requirements.txt and it worked.