# Can't install Pip Packages in El Capitan (10.11)

Tags: python, macos, pip, osx-elcapitan

Okay, so I have brew, and I've brew reinstalled python since El Capitan.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:decipher Alex$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
MacBook-Pro-2:decipher Alex$ whereis python
/usr/bin/python
```

I have two pythons. That's all well and good. Brew doctor is clean, except for some Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include, none of which seem related to Python. Short of virtualenv, is there any way to install packages anymore? I feel like I might be missing something.

[Just like this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted) I was trying to get IPython. I don't really need it, so I gave up the other day. Now I need Pylint. If I try to install it with pip:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logilab_common-1.1.0-py2.7-nspkg.pth'
```

Does anyone know how to point pip towards another instance of python on my system, or do something else so I can have the old behavior back? Please?

-- EDITS --

Suggested was the idea of using /usr/local/bin/pip to install ipython. This is the output. I can't figure out how to use ipython still.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:MNIST Alex$ /usr/local/bin/pip install ipython[all]

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython[all] in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traitlets in /usr/local/bin (from ipython[all])
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pickleshare in /usr/local/bin (from ipython[all])
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplegeneric>0.8 in /usr/local/bin (from ipython[all])
... the rest of the requirements are all satisfied in usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Or pip install --user <package>

Comment: pip install --user seems to work. I don't think you're supposed to use sudo, like the guy mentions in the other stackoverflow post I linked to.

Comment: There is something wrong with your setup as a thing called `/lib` should not exist on OSX or Homebrew install: `ls /lib
/usr/local/bin/gls: cannot access /lib: No such file or directory`

Comment: how peculiar. I have /lib/ and inside, there's **only** python2.7
How did that happen? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mikko Ohtamaa points out in the comments, somehow, I had a version of python in a folder called /lib. I'm not sure how it got there. I think that's the version of python I was using. Once I just `sudo rm -rf /lib` everything suddenly worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble too with El Capitan. I did these things and it worked:

1) Install Homebrew

2) Install Python 3 with Homebrew

3) In terminal enter these installs (in this order)

```
    $ pip3 install pyobjc-core
    $ pip3 install pyobjc
    $ pip3 install pillow
    $ pip3 install pyautogui
```

Answer (score 0):

To point `pip` to another Python instance of your system, you need to use `pip` from the same `bin/` folder where `python` is installed so it resolves to the same `site-packages`.

Example:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip install logilab_common
```

To make `/usr/local/` writable by a local user on OSX do:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/*
```

More information

- http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/89-fix-homebrew-error-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable-on-os-x-el-capitan