# install packages (scipy etc) in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ on OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, osx-elcapitan

I want to install python packages on OS X El Capitan. I saw the SIP was enabled to I disabled it. To make all the changes I want to. I deleted Scipy and Numpy that were installed in:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/
```

I installed Scipy using the following command:

```
sudo pip install --user scipy
```

It still installs it in under:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/
```

I want all my python packages to go under:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

I even tried this:(didnt work)

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/" --ignore-installed scipy
```

So things I want to do:

- Make some config changes so that all my python packages get installed under:   `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`
- Force python to search for packages first under :  `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`
- Also python seems to be picking up setuptools (old version) installed under: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/`

  I want it to use the new version installed under: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.
- So after all these changes every package I update pip updates the on under: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.

My `PYTHONPATH` in my `.bash_profile` is set to  `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

Comment: Why do all this? Install `brew` and you dont ever have to worry about getting into issues with overriding system packages.. EVER!

Comment: I have brew. You mean install python using brew and the use pip to install packages ?

Comment: Yup. Try REALLY hard never to use/touch system packages, install your own version of python (using brew) and i would advice not to install anything in there either other than `virtualenv`. Then in your project use `virtualenv`/ `pyvenv` (py3.x) to install a standalone version and there INSTALL everything you want.

Comment: Backstory: The reason you do this is for compatibility, right now you only have one project, but when you have 3-10 with different package requirements for all, it becomes a LIVING HELL, one want `package-a` v1.2 while another wants `package-a` v2.3 .. what do you do? Simple! If you have all your projects separate no one will care what packages your 2nd project wants. This bit me in the butt a lot when i first started, dont be like me, do things right the first time around :P

Comment: aah ok ! I'll do that thanks !

Comment: Rule of thumb, by the way: if you have to do `sudo pip install ...` you're doing it wrong. There are "some" exceptions, but for right now, avoid it like the plague.

Comment: Please read related answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted/33004920#33004920