# Fix my virtualenv install?

Tags: python, macos

I have no experience at all with python, so when I followed the instructions at https://github.com/unitedstates/congress, I ran the commands:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Which I later read is wrong: [OSX El Capitan: sudo pip install OSError: [Errno: 1] Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted/33004920#33004920)

When I try this command in the guide:

```
mkvirtualenv congress
```

I get an error.

```
-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

Not sure if it ended up installing in an unexpected place or what. Is this where it should be?

```
which virtualenvwrapper.sh
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Please advise on how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `virtualenvwrapper.sh` in your `.bash_profile`, as explained in the [Installation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file) chapter of the virtualenvwrapper docs.

Comment: It looks like I had the wrong source location in the .bash_profile. It should have been: source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh