# Error when installing Cloud Natural Language API Client Libraries for Python on OSX El Capitan

Tags: python-2.7, api, nlp, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries) link from Google to install `Cloud Natural Language API Client Libraries`.

However, when I run:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-language
```

I get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/ng/l9w5y3615ssgmcyt06376k240000ft/T/pip-yy0iba-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I also tried:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-language
```

but got the same error.

I read somewhere that as this is trying to change something on the `/System/Library` OSX El Capitan prevents this.

Is there any suggestion on how to proceed?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Very strange sudo also gave that error but you're way better off running all your Python code inside a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). I understand it's one more tool to learn but it will simplify everything you do from now on greatly, and running lots of commands with `sudo` is a bad idea anyway (what if installation code does evil things?)

[This is the best guide for setting up Python on OS X.](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/), along with the followup section on [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will wait to see if someone is going to answer why I am seeing that issue. If nobody answers I will accept your answer.

Comment: @TJ1 see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted