# I need to install "quandl". But when I type "sudo pip install quandl" in terminal, I get the following error:

Tags: python, linux, machine-learning, ubuntu-16.04, quandl

```
eranga@eranga-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo pip install quandl
The directory '/home/eranga/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/eranga/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting quandl
  Downloading Quandl-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from quandl)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from quandl)
.
.
.
.
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
    building '_openssl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:12:24: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-y31ZOD/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-G6XXj_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-y31ZOD/cryptography/
eranga@eranga-Inspiron-3521:~$
```

Then I tried to manually install "cryptography" using "sudo pip install cryptography" in terminal. Then I got the following error:

```
eranga@eranga-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo pip install cryptography
.
.
.
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
    building '_openssl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:12:24: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-N2rfmu/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-woVGjj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-N2rfmu/cryptography/
eranga@eranga-Inspiron-3521:~$
```

I looked in many sites and read many articles and still could not get rid of this error. I am new to both "quandl" and machine learning. So I would appreciate any detailed approach for me to install "quandl".

Answer (score 0):

Running:

```
pip install quandl
```

without `sudo` works. See Qandl [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Quandl). Running a `sudo pip` is against the python community and bad practice as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted/33004920#33004920) by Mikko Ohtamaa. Using `sudo` will cause `Root` to rewrite package data onto which the normal user then has no write permission anymore.

Comment: It does not work for me. Here is what I get when I run `pip install quandl`.

    `Installing collected packages: pytz, numpy, pandas, cryptography Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
.

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2017.2.dist-info'`