# Numpy Upgrade fails

Tags: python, numpy

```
 sudo pip install numpy --upgrade                                                                                                 PsYcH0
    The directory '/Users/karanj/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    The directory '/Users/karanj/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    Collecting numpy
      Downloading numpy-1.13.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (4.6MB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.6MB 281kB/s
    Installing collected packages: numpy
      Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
        DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
        Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
        requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
        paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
        renames(path, new_path)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
        shutil.move(old, new)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
        copy2(src, real_dst)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
        copystat(src, dst)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
        os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
    OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-tfPgJ6-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Can't get to upgrade numpy because of Errno 1 please help how do I upgrade Numpy.
Tried Unistalling also, but it can't uninstall numpy throws the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX El Capitan: sudo pip install OSError: \[Errno: 1\] Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `python -m pip install SomePackage`. `-m` means that it will install the latest version of the package. Also have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted) for a nice explanation.