# How to open a Jupyter notebook on a Mac?

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook

Maybe this does not work at all, because its a Mac, but maybe there is a way to open a jupyter notebook on a Mac? I tried the following command

```
jupyter notebook Manager.ipynb
```

and I got an error

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Same with out 'notebook':

jupyter Manager.ipynb 
Error executing Jupyter command 'Manager.ipynb': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

There is a file named `Manager.ipynb` in the current folder.

So is there a way to open that notebook on a Mac? Do I have to install some crazy stuff in order to make it work?

Comment: have you installed it yet? http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: can you make sure that `ipynb` file exists in your current directory? of course Jupyter works on Macs and it also looks like it is properly installed on your Mac

Comment: is there some other application with the same name?

Comment: And yes, the file DOES exist in the same directory. I just checked again...

Comment: Not able t install it: "OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share'"

Comment: Probably a Mac issue - again....

Answer (score 2):

The problem I was facing was either a mis-installation of `jupyter`, or there is another application on Macs with the same name. However, (re)install it with this command

```
pip install --user jupyter
```

(a global `pip` install does not seem to work because of some Mac-nonsense, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted)), and then it might work. Or install it in a virtual environment altogether.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be helpful for you, but it's something to know and it's how I access the notebook on my mac.

When I installed Julia, it just came with the command line, I never got the icon to open the notebook or anything of that nature. I had too much trouble trying to install it so I just gave up on getting the icon or a direct link, but if you get Julia installed, you should be able to access the terminal version by entering

```
$ Julia
```

Or clicking on the Julia terminal icon, which will give you this:

[image: Julia terminal]

And then you can just open the notebook by running the following:

```
using IJulia
IJulia.notebook()
```

Also if you're just starting with Julia don't forget you may have to add the package manager by typing `using Pkg` or adding it directly to your code.

This should open it in your default browser (there is no option to open it in a different browser or window). I'm not sure if this is useful but it's an option for those who have trouble installing it like I did.